# Гугл мап по клику

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день. Есть секция со своим фоном и текстом. Нужно чтобы по клику на эту секцию пропадал фон с текстом, и загружалась гугл карта. Как это реализовать ? Спасибо

Comment: Приведите код, который уже есть

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `jQuery`. По клике на кнопку мы можем убрать скрыть блок с помощью `display: none;` и также показать его `display: block;`.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("#block").css({"display" : "none"});
  $("#map").css({"display" : "block"});
});
```

```css
#block {
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #ddd;
}

#map {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Hide block">
<div id="map">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2834.2861264575636!2d3.4958196236363612!3d43.27762534883003!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x367dfec26e8312a4!2sAqualand+Cap+D&#39;Agde!5e1!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1494437348256"
    width="600" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="block"></div>
```